Blazor WebAssembly Hosted on IIS - Error 0x8007000d
I've installed the URL Rewrite module 2.1 but I still receive this error:
Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Código de error    0x8007000d
Archivo de configuración       \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GERO\web.config

This is the web.config created at the time of publish:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Risk.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: FAB573C6-F7A3-417B-9B4D-CE8EBC116F2B-->

I'm missing something? The port is 9090 for the site and I already created a rule to allow it and using .net 6

URL Rewrite module is irrelevant. You need ASP.NET Core module as the linked thread pointed out.
